# Is np.argpartition giving me the wrong results?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Take the following code:

```
import numpy as np
one_dim = np.array([2, 3, 1, 5, 4])
partitioned = np.argpartition(one_dim, 0)
print(f'Unpartitioned array: {one_dim}')
print(f'Partitioned array index: {partitioned}')
print(f'Partitioned array: {one_dim[partitioned]}')
```

The following output results:

```
Unpartitioned array: [2 3 1 5 4]
Partitioned array index: [2 1 0 3 4]
Partitioned array: [1 3 2 5 4]
```

The output for the partitioned array should be [1 2 3 5 4]. How is three on the left side of two? It seems to me the function is making an error or am I missing something?

Comment: `argpartition(ar, 0)` is only responsible for placing the number that should be in position 0 in position 0. It only guarantees that the number on the left is smaller than it and the number on the right is larger than it. It does not guarantee any sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is which index will be in sorted position *after* partitioning, so it is correct that index 0 of the partition (element value 1) is in sorted position, and everything to the right is greater.